# Difference between 'ask' and 'ask for'

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Can I use 'ask' and 'ask for' interchangeably? For example, there's no difference whatsoever (including stylistic difference) between 'ask forgiveness' and 'ask for forgiveness', is there?

Comment: `ask for` is usually used `for making requests,`. Whereas,` ask` use as a question.

Comment: Yes, ask for something versus ask [a question or something].

Comment: The verb `to request` might come handy in avoiding having to use `to ask for`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you *can't*. For example, if you replace the phrase '*ask a question*' with '*ask **for** a question*', it will turn *question* into *requested thing*: the preposition 'for' here precedes that thing (= the person who asks would like *to be asked a question*). Sometimes, in *informal* speech that preposition (before the desired 'forgiveness' in your example) is omitted, but it can't be *added* into a phrase about *asking a question*.

Comment: Your answer is a bit confusing.